# RxJs lastValueFrom scheduled asapScheduler strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have this script for play with `scheduled`/`asapScheduler` but I found a  strange behaviour in combination with `lastValueFrom`:

```
import { of, lastValueFrom, scheduled, asapScheduler } from 'rxjs';

const bbj = { foo: 'bar' };

async function foo() {
  const result = await lastValueFrom(scheduled(of(bbj), asapScheduler));
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

async function main() {
  await foo(); // 1° console log
  await foo(); // 2° console log
  await foo(); // 3° console log
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  main();
});
```

the expected behaviour is on button click, 3 console log, eg.:

```
{foo: "bar"}
{foo: "bar"}
{foo: "bar"}
```

But on first click it produce NO console log

On second click it produce 5 console log:

```
{foo: "bar"}
{foo: "bar"}
{foo: "bar"}
{foo: "bar"}
{foo: "bar"}
```

and on third click, 1 console log:

```
{foo: "bar"}
```

Why not produce 3 console log on each click?

try online https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mkgftu?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: I do not see the behavior you describe. What I see is that the *first* click produces *no* console output; it's on the *second* click that I see 5.

Comment: Yes, I have made a mistake. But why not produce 3 console log on each click?

Comment: I think it has to do with the way `lastValueFrom()` works. There are 5 messages on the second click: the 3 from the first click, and 2 of the three from the second click. I'm not sure exactly why it's doing that however.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the `of()` sequence never ends. If you replace `of(bbj)` with a generator function that yields a fixed set of values, then it works the way you expect.

Comment: Honestly I'm more confused by the fact that the `lastValueFrom()` Promise *ever* resolves, and I have no clue why starting the `main()` function again makes that happen.

Comment: @Pointy what type of generatore function fix the problema?

Comment: `function* g() { let c = 0; while (c < 10) yield c++; }` — if you pass `g()` instead of `of(bbj)` it will behave as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed with custom of: `function* _of<T>(value: T): Generator<T> {
  yield value;
}`

Comment: Well I'm glad that works but I think I'm more confused than ever now :)